# CSS & LESS - Gradient & Border issue

Tags: html, css, less

```
<div class="menu_wrapper">
<div class="menu_entry"><p class="text_menu_entry">{$uiStrings['ui_text_view']}</p></div>
<div class="menu_entry"><p class="text_menu_entry">{$uiStrings['ui_text_add']}</p></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z8J9q/1/

ALL CSS is on the jsfiddle...

Why this code on hover, makes 1 of the borders, bottom, 100% colored. Like a line...

You can also check live on my project: http://alpt.twomini.com/

Click "Fleet", on the right column, MENU AREA. Hover the menu items...

I thank you all, your time, patience and answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule to your :hover definition

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Borders are inside of the element. Since you have it semi-transparent and background is set to repeat by default then you see the gradient making it 'less transparent'

Comment: Worked perfectly fine! Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use background-clip : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z8J9q/2/)**

```
 background-clip:padding-box;/* do not draw background under borders */
```

Add prefix if needed. You can check use and supports **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)**

Comment: Worked perfectly fine! Thank you for the explanation.